# Ionic ion-content not adjusting properly when keyboard shows

Tags: angularjs, sass, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I've a view with textangular as an element. On Android(I tested), if the keyboard is opened, the view is not scrolling up to prevent the editor from getting behind the keyboard.
I installed the Keyboard plugin com.ionic.keyboard.

This is the structure of the page:

```
<ion-view id="newblogview">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    ...
    </ion-nav-buttons>    
  <ion-content scroll="true" overflow-scroll="true" class="has-header" delegate-handle="mainScroll">  
     <iframe data-tap-disabled="true" style="width: 100%; min-height: 100%"  src="./templates/blog/html/blog-editor.html" name="blogeditor" id="blogeditor"></iframe>                
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

it's not moving up when the keyboard is opened by focusing on the input.
I've tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and also "adjustResize"
And also I've tried native.keyboardshow event to call $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);

I think we've Keyboard attach directive for footer, but I can't place text editor in the footer.
Does ionic framework support adjusting ion content to keyboard show/hide? is this feature is not supported yet in framework or am I missing something.

This question is similar to [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837270/ionic-ion-content-not-scrolling-down-when-keyboard-shows-android), but there is no accepted answer.

Please help.
-Prakash.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your html component

```
<div delegate-handle="toThisPosition" ng-click="GoHere()"> </div>
```

and adding this to the ng-click method GoHere() in your controller:

```
GoHere() {
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('toThisPosition').scrollBottom(true);
}
```